# Can't install libgtk2.0-dev on linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am trying to compile xfce-terminal, configure will not pass saying I lack gtk2

```
checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.24.0... not found
*** The required package gtk+-2.0 was not found on your system.
*** Please install gtk+-2.0 (atleast version 2.24.0) or adjust
```

So I am trying to install "sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev"

Then I get real weird output (including internal error):

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Reading extended state information...
Initializing package states...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-gtk-2.0{a} libatk1.0-dev{a} libcairo-script-interpreter2{a} 
  libcairo2-dev{a} libexpat1-dev{a} libfontconfig1-dev{a} 
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev{a} libglib2.0-dev{a} libgtk2.0-dev libice-dev{a} 
  libpango1.0-dev{a} libpcre3-dev{a} libpcrecpp0{a} libpixman-1-dev{a} 
  libsm-dev{a} libxcb-shm0-dev{a} libxcomposite-dev{a} libxcursor-dev{a} 
  libxft-dev{a} libxinerama-dev{a} libxml2-utils{a} 
  x11proto-composite-dev{a} x11proto-xinerama-dev{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gir1.2-pango-1.0 libpango-1.0-0 libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0 
  libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 
  libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 
9 packages upgraded, 23 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,023 kB of archives. After unpacking 43.7 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpango1.0-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed.
                 Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed.
                 Depends: libpangoxft-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed.
                 Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed.
 libpango1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0:i386 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed.
                      Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed.
                      Depends: libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed.
                      Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:
1)      apturl                      
2)      banshee                     
3)      gir1.2-gkbd-3.0             
4)      gkbd-capplet                
5)      gtk2-engines-murrine        
6)      gtk2-engines-murrine:i386   
7)      ia32-libs                   
8)      libappindicator0.1-cil      
9)      libgnomekbd8                
10)     libgtk-sharp-beans-cil      
11)     libgtk2.0-cil               
12)     libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil   
13)     libnotify0.4-cil            
14)     libpango1.0-0               
15)     libpango1.0-0:i386          
16)     libvte9                     
17)     mint-meta-core              
18)     mint-meta-xfce              
19)     mintbackup                  
20)     mintinstall                 
21)     mintwelcome                 
22)     python-sexy                 
23)     python-vte                  
24)     tomboy                      
25)     xfce4-dict                  
26)     xfce4-terminal              
27)     xfce4-weather-plugin        



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Should I proceed or what should I do to get GTK2 installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't proceed with this solution, it will remove mint-meta-core which is an essential package for mint and mint-meta-xfce which is the xfce session itself...

why not install xfce-terminal from `apt install xfce-terminal`?

Comment: since I wanted to read the sources and compile. By the way I solved the problem, or rather after few days it just disappeared and I was able to install the package without these warnings. Very strange.